# How to bind material input with nested FormControl?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a reactive form and I want to bind material input with a FormControl.
When I use a raw html input like below, everything is ok:

`<input type="text" formControlName="forContractor" />`

but if I use mat-form-field like below, I get: "forContractor" highlighted with error message "Identifier 'forContractor' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a memberng"

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Contractor name</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Contractor name" [formControl]="forContractor" />
</mat-form-field>
```

component class:

```
addInvoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    forContractor: [""],
});
```

I figured out, that if I create a property for this control and then assign it to the FormControl, a then bind this property with a template, problem dissappears. However, this looks odd, especially that I have 10 controls for this form.
Is there a method to do this without creating a property for every control?

Odd solution:

```
forContractorControl = new FormControl("");

addInvoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    forContractor: this.forContractorControl,
});

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Contractor name</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Contractor name" [formControl]="forContractorControl" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `mat-form-field` in a `<form></form>` tag and then specify the group like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="addInvoiceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Contractor name</mat-label>
   <input matInput placeholder="Contractor name" formControlName="forContractorControl" />
 </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I have done a lot of forms in angular material and ended up building my own library, you can check it out here [ngx-mat-dynamic-form-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-dynamic-form-builder) and live [example](https://stackblitz.com/github/lukekroon/ngx-mat-dynamic-form-builder)